# Is a TCP socket secure or should I always check the user

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, ssl, tcp

I have a C++ app that connects to a nodeJS server through a TCP socket.
On socket 'handshake' the client authenticates itself with a UUID known by the server, the server then associates the account to this recognised UUID

Once a TCP socket is open, the app sends requests and the server answers through the same socket.

Is it necessary to add passphrase to every request to be sure the request comes from the client? Or is a socket supposed to be in place and remain in place?

So should I be sure the client is the client:

- Only when opening the socket?
- Every time a request is made?

Comment: There is a saying that goes "Never trust the client". Just using an UUID is not enough for anything slightly sensitive or critical.

Comment: Consider wrapping the connection in TLS and giving the user a certificate instead of a UUID.  If anyone can sniff the password, it’s useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UUID known to the server is normally called a token. And it can be used for your scenario. However it should never be done unencrypted.
What you need to make sure is the following:

- An external party (not one of the 2 members of the communication) should not be able to read the token.
- The client should not connect to anything but YOUR server.

This is typically accomplished using TLS. (This is what makes HTTPS secure.)

I suggest you do some research into token-based authentication/authorization and TLS/SSL.

One last advice: do not implement the encryption code yourself but use a well used library that has as a result had a lot of testing and has good maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the whole story quite clear. I'm using a token based authentification over TLS , everything looks ok, well it's a self-signed certificate, but I do believe this is not all that bad if I'm coding the client too.

Comment: @VincentDuprez If you use a self-signed certificate and distribute it together with the application then the only disadvantage I see is should the private key be leaked, there wouldn't be a way for you to revoke that certificate, while CA's have a method for this. However if you are doing this only for the learning experience then self-signed certificates are more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not "secure". Your scheme is susceptible to, just off the top of my head, replay attacks, man-in-the-middle attacks, eavesdropping, subsequent impersonation ...

A socket isn't like an actual physical pipe or tunnel. A socket is just an agreement that data marked with a certain source and destination port pair (these are just numbers) are to be treated as belonging to a particular logical data channel. This is determined by handshake and trust. There is no verification.

**What you're specifically asking is whether man-in-the-middle attacks exist. Yes, yes they do.**

Will requiring a passphrase be given in each packet fix that problem? No, it won't. It will be trivial to intercept and then replay. You're just giving the man in the middle the passphrase.

This is why people use encryption and other clever security schemes. If you're concerned about message authenticity and integrity, you'll need a basic grounding in communications security principles; providing one is out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: So very basically, You're telling me I should use a secure socket + authenticate every request with a one-time token, so the man i the middle is unable to reproduce a valid request. is that right?

Comment: @VincentDuprez: I'm curious as to why you're trying to re-invent basic security principles with no grounding? Which computer network security book are you using?

Comment: I'm not trying to reinvent, I'm new to all this, and trying to make my setup work, there's nothing critical going on, just learning. how everything works

Comment: @VincentDuprez: You _are_ trying to reinvent! Which computer network security book are you using?

Comment: Google basically... I got your message.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why so intent on pushing a book on him? Sure it can help but if he is not building something that will see real use, let him build, learn and fail, how else do you learn? Try to point him in the right direction, let him do his research. And trying to reinvent something is a great learning experience.

Comment: @Selenog: Learn from a good book rather than ask us to reproduce its contents here. Come back with any questions _after_ the research phase has been completed, not before.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is how you felt reading my question. I think my question is broad enough and that a lot of users may be asking this, so I think this could be on SO, not only in a book I don't have.

Comment: @VincentDuprez: SO is for specific questions, not broad ones!!! Honestly, get yourself a book on computer network security and brush up. Then you'll know this stuff automatically. I am trying to help you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did not want to imply you did not want to help him. And the question is indeed very basic (and shows little research) but to do research you need a starting point. That is why in my answer I tried to send him in the correct direction without explaining any specifics.